# macOS: Settings window positioning

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, nswindow

I would like to position the Settings window, e.g.:

- Horizontal: centered in the screen
- Vertical: 200px from screen top

The code below does position it, but with some delay. It first appears where the system decides to put it, then my positioning is applied. I would like to avoid this "flash" effect.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MacosPlaygroundApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("Playground") {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .frame(width: 700, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        }
        Settings {
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {

    @State private var selectedTab: SettingsTab = .first

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("First settings")
                .tabItem { Label("First", systemImage: "1.square") }
                .tag(SettingsTab.first)

            Text("Second settings")
                .tabItem { Label("Second", systemImage: "2.square") }
                .tag(SettingsTab.second)
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 200, alignment: .top)
        .onAppear {
            // I wrap it in a Task because `settingsWindow` would be `nil` otherwise
            Task {
                guard let settingsWindow = NSApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.title == windowTitle }) else { return }
                guard let screen = settingsWindow.screen else { return }
                let settingsWindowSize = settingsWindow.frame.size
                let screenSize = screen.frame.size
                let left = (screenSize.width - settingsWindowSize.width) / 2
                let bottom = screenSize.height - 200
                settingsWindow.setFrameTopLeftPoint(NSPoint(x: left, y: bottom))
            }
        }
    }

    var windowTitle: String {
        switch selectedTab {
        case .first:
            return "First"
        case .second:
            return "Second"
        }
    }

    enum SettingsTab {
        case first
        case second
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Task` works asynchronously, a *delay* is normal. I would not calculate the position in the view, preferred in a view model. Actually you do know the size of the window, you only need to determine the size of the screen.

Comment: I look for a way to avoid the delay. I understand that now the delay is because I do the positioning async in a Task. As I commented in the code, I do the positioning in the Task because without it, the settings window is not there in `NSApplication.shared.windows`. Do you know a way (e.g. somewhere earlier in the window or view lifecycle) where I already can access the settings window, to avoid the delay? To clarify, my problem with the delay is the flash effect, i.e. the window first appears somewhere I do not control, there it's moved to where I position it.